# Reactive Extensions: How can I layer observables?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a service which publishes generic messages, and I have created an observable for those messages. These messages can contain anything, and different protocols can be layered on top.

I wish to add a second layer observable to interpret a particular protocol from these messages. For instance, the messages can be of type "update", "error" or "complete". I wish to re-publish "update" messages, throw an error on "errors", and complete the sequence on "complete".

How can I achieve this cleanly?

I don't think I can use `SelectMany` to do this; while the selector can return `Observable.Return()` or `Observable.Throw()` for the first two cases, there's no way I can complete from the selector (call `observer.OnCompleted()` and unsubscribe from the underlying observable).

It appears to me I have to use `Observable.Create()` and subscribe to the underlying observable inside the subscribe method. I've done that but the implementation feels weird to me, because it's not using the functional composition style more common in Rx. Is it the right way to do it?

```
public IObservable<Message> InterpretProtocol(IObservable<message> stream)
{
  return Observable.Create<Message>(observer =>
  {
    return stream.Subscribe(message =>
    {
      switch (ProtocolMessageTypeOf(message))
      {
        case ProtocolMessageType.Error:
          observer.OnError(new InvalidOperationException(message));
          break;

        case ProtocolMessageType.Complete:
          observer.OnCompleted();
          break;

        default:
          observer.OnNext(message);
          break;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
public IObservable<Message> InterpretProtocol(IObservable<message> stream) {

  return stream.
         TakeWhile(msg => ProtocolMessageTypeOf(message) != ProtocolMessageType.Complete).
         Select(msg => {
             if(ProtocolMessageTypeOf(message) == ProtocolMessageType.Error)
               throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
             else
               return msg;
        });

}
```